# solidity : error information Source file requires different compiler version

Tags: compiler-errors, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

When compiling the lottery.sol, met this compiler error,
as a rookie to development, didn't quite understand the error, what's the solution to solve this compiler version issue, it's really frustrating...

```
Compiling contracts...
  Solc version: 0.6.12
  Optimizer: Enabled  Runs: 200
  EVM Version: Istanbul
CompilerError: solc returned the following errors:

/Users/liwei/.brownie/packages/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1/contracts/src/v0.6/vendor/SafeMathChainlink.sol:2:1: ParserError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.6.12+commit.27d51765.Darwin.appleclang) - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
```

lottery.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier:MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/VRFConsumerBase.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/vendor/SafeMathChainlink.sol";

contract Lottery is VRFConsumerBase, Ownable {
    AggregatorV3Interface internal ethUsdPriceFeed;
    uint256 usdEntryFee;
    address[] public players;
    bytes32 internal keyHash; //public key to generate randomness,uniquely identify the chainlink node.
    uint256 internal fee;
    uint256 public randomness;

    enum LOTTERY_STATE {
        OPEN,
        CLOSED,
        CALCULATING_WINNER
    }
    LOTTERY_STATE public lottery_state;

    constructor(
        address _priceFeedAddress,
        address _VRFCoordinator, //contract to validate the random number
        address _link, //address to pay oracle gas
        uint256 _fee,
        bytes32 _keyhash
    ) public VRFConsumerBase(_vrfCoordinator, _link) {
        usdEntryFee = 50 * (10**18);
        ethUsdPriceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(_priceFeedAddress);
        lottery_state = CLOSED;
        fee = _fee;
        keyhash = _keyhash;
    }

    function enter() public payable {
        require(lottery_state == OPEN);
        // require amount>=entrance fee ($50 in Ether)
        require(msg.value >= getEntranceFee(), "Not enought ETH!");
        // push player's address into the the array
        players.push(msg.sender);
    }

    function getEntranceFee() public view returns (uint256) {
        (, int256 price, , , ) = ethUsdPriceFeed.latestRoundData();
        uint256 adjustedPrice = uint256(price) * (10**10); // 18 decimals
        // $50,$2,000 / ETH
        // 50/2,000
        // 50 *100000 / 20000
        uint256 costToEnter = (usdEntryFee * 10**18) / adjustedPrice; //usdEntryFee has additional 18 decimals
        return costToEnter;
    }

    function startLottery() public {
        require(lottery_state == CLOSED, "Can't start a new lottery yet");
        lottery_state = LOTTERY_STATE.OPEN;
    }

    function endLottery() public {
        lottery_state = LOTTERY_STATE.CLOSED;
        require(
            LINK.balanceOf(address(this)) >= fee,
            "Not enough LINK - fill contract with faucet"
        );
        bytes32 requestId = requestRandomness(keyHash, fee); // make the inital request for randomness
    }

    function fulfillRandomness(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _randomness)
        internal
        override
    {
        require(
            lottery_state == LOTTERY_STATE.CALCULATING_WINNER,
            "You are n't there yet !"
        );
        require(_randomness > 0, "radnom-not-found !");
        uint256 indexOfWinner = _radonmness % players.length; // get the remainder,Modulo pattern
        recentWinner = players[indexOfWinner];
        rencentWinner.tranfer(address(this).balance);

        // reset the players array

        players = new address payable[](0);
        lottery_state = LOTTERY_STATE.CLOSED;
        randomness = _randomness;
    }
}
```

After changing the compiler version as the error information suggested, it suggested switching the compiler version back.

```
New compatible solc version available: 0.8.11
Compiling contracts...
  Solc version: 0.8.11
  Optimizer: Enabled  Runs: 200
  EVM Version: Istanbul
CompilerError: solc returned the following errors:

ParserError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.8.11+commit.d7f03943.Darwin.appleclang) - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
 --> /Users/liwei/.brownie/packages/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0/contracts/access/Ownable.sol:3:1:
  |
3 | pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.8.0;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


ParserError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.8.11+commit.d7f03943.Darwin.appleclang) - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
 --> /Users/liwei/.brownie/packages/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1/contracts/src/v0.6/VRFConsumerBase.sol:2:1:
  |
2 | pragma solidity ^0.6.0;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

(base) liwei@liweideMacBook-Pro smartcontract-lottery2022 %
```

Answer (score 0):

It pointed out that `SafeMathChainlink.sol` use another compiler version, which is incompatible with the one you're using.

So here are something you could try:

- Import the `SafeMathChainlink.sol` complied with `0.6.x` instead of `0.7-0.9`.
- Change the compiler to `0.7.x` and looks for the `VRFConsumerBase.sol` complied with `0.7.x` (Might be something like: `@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/VRFConsumerBase.sol`)
- If the two things above is impossible, than you can create `VRFConsumerBase.sol` or `VRFConsumerBase.sol` yourself with the compiler version you desired to use.

Comment: the issue is different imported contract require different version of comipiler and they are not compatitble.

VRFConsumerBase,SafeMathChainlink,Ownable are the smart contract create by others ,not me , I am not there yet.

Comment: Yeah, so that's why I mentioned that we should find the appropriate version, might be via the official doc. Another thing you can to try is remove `import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/vendor/SafeMathChainlink.sol";`. If there's error, and you can try to use a simple SafeMath module instead.